# Trying to print user input from a plain text (box) on the same activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple list sort of app where the user enters text in the plain text box and when they press the ok button, their message prints below (on the same activity). the android  tutorial shows how to print it on a different screen but I'm trying to do it on the same screen

Here's my mainactivity.java code

```
 package com.example.shoppinglist;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {

    }
}
```

This is the activity_main.xml if you mean this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shoppinglist.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/edit_message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show your `activity_main.xml` its more important here! Edit your question and add it!

Comment: do you mean the layout?

Comment: Not the Layout graphical, I mean the texts layout not the Image?

Comment: where do I find that?

Comment: Exactly! Thats what I was saying!

Comment: Sorry I have updated my answer, there was a mistake in the initial answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `TextView` and set its `ID` as `textView` after that change your method `sendMessage` to look like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String textWritten = editText.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(textWritten);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Do Like this:
     package com.example.shoppinglist;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      Button   btnClk ;
      TextView textView ;
      EditText editText ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
           textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            btnClk   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClk);

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       String textValue= editText.getText.toString();
       sendMessage(textValue);
       }
     });

 }

        public void sendMessage(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
```